# Set individual Airplay device volume using Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes, airplay

I can tell iTunes to play a track to multiple Airplay speakers but I can't figure out how to set the volume for each device individually. I can control the overall iTunes volume but not each device separately.

[Dougs scripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/2013/05/project-change-airplay-speakers-change-eq/) mentions:

> So also: smarties can probably figure out how to set a discrete volume for each chosen device using the Airplay device sound volume property.

but I'm not a smartie and can't figure out how this is set, [this page](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/2013/05/airplay-device-properties/) suggests these properties can be set in Applescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can indeed. You do it like this:

```
tell application "iTunes" to set sound volume of AirPlay device "Apple TV" to 99
```

The volume is an integer from 0 to 100 (99 in this example). Just substitute whatever your AirPlay device's name is.